# Looking for a cross-browser Solution to clip a div

Tags: canvas, responsive-design, cross-browser, css-shapes, clip-path

Working on a project where I have to create a div behind a semi transparent PNG. So with the div I can change color, but the div has to be different shape to match with image (PNG).

Sample:

[image: Cropped div sample]

Tried HTML Canvas, CSS shape, CSS Clip-path, solution for one browser is not working in other and solution for desktop view is not working on mobile view.

Looking for a solution to crop a div as shown in the attachment which should work in all browsers and all device (responsive).

Thanks all

Comment: Thanks friend. Your post helps a lot. Cheers